# Detect when user cancels input field in Vim

Tags: vim

I'm writing a custom function within Vim and asking the user to choose the file to rename:

`let b:newname = input('Rename to: ', expand('%'))`

However, should the user decide not to rename the file and press `Esc`, how does one detect this within a Vim function?

Comment: You can check the value of the variable if it is empty or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the use cancels the operation, input returns an empty value. So you can check that directly with `empty()`:

```
if empty(b:newname)
    " either cancelled or empty answer
endif
```

Comment: but this won't differ the case that: 1. the user wants to enter an empty value to update whatever function the input data is used; 2. the user wants to cancel the input process.

Comment: Is there a way to distinguish between a `\n` newline and an empty value?

Comment: Yes, but `input()` won't send a trailing `\n`. I don't think there is a way to distinguish empty from cancelled in this case. One alternative is to use `inputdialog()`.

Comment: Found this answer that using `getchar()` should make the difference: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/8529/how-to-define-an-operator-which-is-updating-while-it-is-taking-input