# In Vim, how to distinguish between a newline `\n` and an empty value returned by the input() function?

Tags: regex, vim

I'm writing a custom function within Vim and asking the user to input some info for use:

`let x = input('Do input: ')`

`(update an entry with x)`

However, I'd like to distinguish the two different cases:

1. the user enters an empty value so that the function will clear the previous value of the entry;
2. the user cancels the input process by pressing `ESC`.

Is it possible to do this?
If not using `input()`, what else I can do?

A similar question is here:

[Detect when user cancels input field in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43241610/detect-when-user-cancels-input-field-in-vim/43242403?noredirect=1#comment98946059_43242403)

But I need a more detailed control.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a bit to experiment with input with the following code:

```
function! Foo()
    let x = input('Do input: ')
    execute "normal i".x
    echo "Foo called with: ".x
endfunc
command -nargs=0 Foo call Foo()
```

Here are the following behaviours:

- Pressing `Return` adds in the document the value typed by the user and prints the `echo` line,
- Pressing `Escape` seems to have the same effect as typing nothing and pressing `Return`, nothing is added in the document and the `echo` line is printed, with no value for `x`,
- Pressing `C-c` (Control C, similar to escape, but not quite. CF `:help i_^c`), the input and the function execution are cancelled, the `echo` line is not executed.

So I would say that you can consider `escape` (shortcut for emptying the input and pressing `return`) and an empty input as the same, and consider `CTRL-c` an the input being cancelled.

However, I am not sure that you can, while staying in the function, detect that the user cancelled the input or not, but hopefully someone will know better than me to confirm or correct this.